# Do malicious web sites ever exploit vulnerabilities in Linux clients?

Tags: linux, security, internet-security

Do malicious web sites ever exploit vulnerabilities in Linux clients?

Are there any ***documented*** instances of this happening in the wild?

I am talking about actually taking over the client's machine rather than cross-site scripting.

Also, I'm not asking whether it's possible in theory (of course it is, otherwise they wouldn't be vulnerabilities), but if anyone **actually bothers** to go after Linux users.

Comment: Yes. Documented... some not many. Why these are not that much in the news... because the target audience is not big compared to ... say Windows OS viruses. Also due to the differences in linux variant, it is actually hard to infect any Linux OS (or create a binary that runs on all variant out there) - so yes they exist, but not all that much - but exist.

Comment: I've seen a few ad networks target specific browser vulnerabilities. For instance, Chrome had/has a defect that allowed one of the ad networks used on cracked dot com to run their own crap on Windows. It messed with a Mac a bit too, but not as bad. We didn't have a Linux machine to test it, but I imagine the vulnerability was there, just not as effective perhaps... -- DO NOT access that site using Chrome. Our admin tested it and had to reset his Chrome settings as well. (This was about 4 weeks ago.)

Answer (score 0):

**Of course they do.**

There are many websites that try to install you a browser extension to show ads in every website you visit. Specially in Chrome.

There are also viruses for **Linux** systems.

You can find many virus or rootkits for linux, the problem is that obviously, at some point, they will need you to enter your root password to get installed.

But imagine this situation, you download a package thinking that it is Google Chrome, but in fact it is a virus. 
You open it, enter your root password, install it and at the end of the process it shows an error.
You will think there was a problem with it and will go to google and download it again.

By the end of the day, you will have a nice VIRUS + Google chrome on your invencible linux system.

So IT IS very important that you download your packages from reliable sources and check the file integrity against the MD5/SHA1 hash (checksum) provided by the software developer to make sure you have what you were looking for.

Comment: **check also the MD5 fingerprints to make sure those packages were not changed** -- that's not what MD5 is for. Google "md5 forgery". The whole answer is beyond ignorant.

Comment: @MaxB Would you have been happier if it said "check the MD5 and SHA1 hashes"?

Comment: The MD5/SHA1 fingerprints can mean nothing whatsoever if they come from the same website as the download, as the Linux Mint website hack shows.